# Pass parameters in a stored procedure in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a stored procedure in my sql database and I want to call it from a java program (with spring) using `@Procedure` annotation. So far so good.

I call the procedure with `@Procedure(procedureName = "my_procedure")`. The problem is that I want to pass 2 parameters inside the procedure.

Is there a way to accomplish that using the `@Procedure` annotation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution!

@Procedure annotation can be used to map a method with a stored procedure if the name is the same and it is smart enough to map the method variables to the procedure parameters if they are the same type. However to commit the changes to the db , you have to use the Transactional annotation.
ex.

```
@Procedure
@Transactional
void MyProcedureName(Integer par1 , Integer par2);
```

The above code will call the procedure MyProcedureName from the db and will map par1 and par2 to the MyProcedureName parameter 1 and parameter 2.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-annotations), and [this](http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-hibernate-jpa-2-1/) article may be helpful.

First, you need to declare procedure on entity:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({ 
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "my_procedure", 
        procedureName = "schema.my_procedure", 
        parameters = { 
            @StoredProcedureParameter(
                mode = ParameterMode.IN, 
                name = "first", 
                type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(
                mode = ParameterMode.IN, 
                name = "second", 
                type = String.class) 
            },
            @StoredProcedureParameter(
                mode = ParameterMode.OUT, 
                name = "result", 
                type = Long.class) 
            }
    ) 
})
```

Second, refer to it in your repository

```
@Procedure(name = "my_procedure")
long getResult(@Param("first") String first, @Param("second") String second);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have already read these articles.
I do not want to use NamedStoredProcedureQuery .
What I do now is :
    @Procedure
     void myProcedureName(int par1 , int par2);
The strange thing is that if I use primary key that already exists in par1 I get an error of duplicate primary key.
But if the primary key is not present in my db is does not write it. 
It is like the code cannot commit the query..

Comment: I've never do it by myself, but according to https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/stored-procedure.html - @Param annotation should work. Use param name as in the database procedure. Do you tried this way?